# Get DateFormatter From my iPhone Programatically

Tags: ios, datetime, nsdateformatter

I want to use **DateFormatter** in my iphone app. which is used in **Setting->General->Date&Time.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Apple Doc here will help you https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Answer (score 1):

To use the default local (this is what the user select in  **Setting->General->Date&Time**) Apple provides a quick method [`localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW52)

To get for example only the date use:

```
NSString *datePresentaion = 
[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:someDate dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

Of if you are creating an instance of `NSDateFormatter` you will need to tell it which local to user:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Comment: @Rushabh can you give an example of the code you use, because if you pass a valid date to this method there is no way it returns `nil`